# How to Replace string and loop between commas with another string

Tags: vb.net

can you help me how to get Index of the same string and replace it one by one with another string?

Here my example code :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
    Dim str As String = "abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd"
    Dim replace As String = "efgh"
    Dim value As String
    value = str.Replace("abcd", replace)
    TextBox4.AppendText(value)
Next
```

The value will be result : ***efgh,efgh,efgh,efgh,efgh...***

How i can create the result like this :

***efgh***,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd...

for the next loop it will be like this :

*abcd,**efgh**,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd...*

for the next loop it will be like this :

*abcd,abcd,**efgh**,abcd,abcd,abcd...*

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mark mentioned there are lots of ways this could be done. One of this ways to add and remove ranges in a string is to use the `StringBuilder`.

```
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For i As Integer = 0 To 35 Step 5
      Dim sDefaultString As String = "abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd"
      Dim sbText = New StringBuilder(sDefaultString)
      sbText.Remove(i, 4)
      sbText.Insert(i, "efgh")
      TextBox1.AppendText(sbText.ToString & vbNewLine)
    Next

  End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much sir, my problem have solved, i'll learn more about StringBuilder method, thanks

Comment: Nice solution.  Using `sbText.Replace("abcd", "efgh", i, 4)` instead of `Remove` and `Insert` may be more efficient.

Comment: Creating new instance of `StringBuilder` in the every loop not so efficient. Then what if you need to change string `abcdef,abcdef,abcdef` to "fedcba,abcdef,abcdef"

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways this could be done.  One *perhaps inefficient* way would be to split the string at the commas, replace the appropriate item in the resulting array, and then join the array back up.

```
Dim str As String = "abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd"
Dim replace As String = "efgh"
For i As Integer = 0 To str.Count(Function(x) x = ","c)
    Dim strParts = str.Split(","c)
    strParts(i) = replace
    Dim value As String = String.Join(",", strParts)
    Console.WriteLine(value)
Next
```

Output:

```
efgh,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd
abcd,efgh,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd
abcd,abcd,efgh,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd
abcd,abcd,abcd,efgh,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd
abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,efgh,abcd,abcd,abcd
abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,efgh,abcd,abcd
abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,efgh,abcd
abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,abcd,efgh
```

Comment: str.Count is not a member of string, can you explain that? btw thanks for your answer.

Comment: @HarisonMatondang A `String` is an `IEnumerable(Of Char)`, so the `Count` method here is the [`Enumerable.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method from LINQ.  You will need .NET 3.5+ and to import `System.Linq` for it to work.

Comment: Thank's sir, your answer's very useful, i'll try it now.